# Wait for external event in acceptance tests

Tags: ember.js

In an Ember 2.3 app, I'm using stripe and I have this acceptance test :

```
  it('can visit /user-subscription', () => {
    visit('/');

    andThen(() => {
      click('#pay');
      andThen(() => {
        fillIn('#card_number', '4242424242424242');
        fillIn('#cc-exp', '1299');
        fillIn('#cc-csc', '444');
        click('#submitButton');

        andThen(() => {
          done();
          expect(currentPath()).to.equal('subscriptions.success');
       });
      });
    });
  });
```

When I click on `pay` button, it show the Stripe box with this code :

```
  var checkout = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: "...",
    locale: 'fr'
  }).open({
    email: owner.get('email'),
    amount: price,
    token: (result) => {
      # ...
    }
  });
```

It loads and execute and external script. The test is failing before the box is displayed. The external script is not loaded completely when the test fail.

I'm using EmberCliMirage with `this.passthrough('https://checkout.stripe.com/**');`.

What can I do to make the test pass?

Answer (score 0):

You can pause the test until you receive the event.  https://api.qunitjs.com/async/

```
let eventReceived = assert.async();

// ... callback for that async event ... 
function eventComplete() {
  eventReceived();
  // ... do some more assertions
}

// supply the callback to something that knows about the external event
```

Comment: It still not work. I also tried with `Ember.run.start` and `Ember.run.stop` and I have `timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`. I'm looking for a way to have a long time but I don't find.

Comment: I found a way to increase the timeout but I still have this error.